# problem with makefile , No rule to make target [C]

Tags: c, makefile

Hi guys I'm trying to run this makefile but the terminal gives me the output:

```
 make: *** No rule to make target 'abc'. Stop.
```

This is the makefile

```
CFLAGS = -Wall
CC = gcc
LP = -lpthread

all: abc

abc: exam.o memorizer.o
      $(CC) $(LP) exam.o memorizer.o

exam.o: exam.c
      $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) $(LP) exam.c -o exam.o

memorizer. or: memorizer.c
      $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) memorizer.c -o memorizer.o

clean:
      rm *.o abc
```

What can i do ?

Comment: Is that your exact makefile? The commands for each target need to be tabbed. And you can't have spaces between `$`  and the variable being expanded.

Comment: @kaylum That should be the answer. Additionally `rm * .o abc` is evil, the space between `*` and `.o` changes everything. This command deletes all files in the directory.

Comment: I agree with @kaylum's comments but that can't be the issue here.  If the makefile were exactly as typed here then there would be a syntax error, not a "no rule to make target".  Please show the exact make command you typed and the exact error you got, and tell us the filename of your makefile.  My suspicion is that you named your makefile something non-standard, then typed `make abc` on the command line.

Comment: @mch We don't have enough info to say that that is the answer. It's certainly somethings that could be wrong about the makfile but may not explain the exact symptoms. Am hoping that the OP will be updated and clarified.

Comment: sorry the copy and paste failed, now I have readjusted the makefile. The name of the makefile is "Makefile" and the terminal gives me back what I wrote above.

Comment: Replace `memorizer. or: memorizer.c` by `memorizer.o: memorizer.c` and things should be better.

Comment: I tried to fix the makefile but it still doesn't work. The thing I don't understand is because if I execute the command: "make abc" it returns me what I wrote above, while if I write "make -f Makefile.mak"
it seems to compile in fact it also gives me some warnings then but it tells me:
/ usr / bin / ld: /tmp/ccBHd9Tg.o: in function `main ':
/home/pollo/exam.c:111: undefined reference to `pthread_create '
/ usr / bin / ld: /home/pollo/exam.c:122: undefined reference to `pthread_join '
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile.mak: 12: exam.o] Error 1

Comment: Above you say that the file is named `Makefile` but in the previous comment you say you need to run `make -f Makefile.mak`.  So, which is correct?  Is the file named `Makefile`, or is it named `Makefile.mak`?

Answer (score 1):

Do exam.o and memorizer.o files exist when you run make?
Missing a dependency file would lead to "make: *** No rule to make target", although I think the complete output would show something like "needed by ''"

Comment: This is not an answer, should be probably added as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you missed `.o` at the end of the `$(CC)` commands (and made a typo in the `memorizer` target):

```
exam.o: exam.c
      $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) (LP) exam.c -o exam.o

memorizer.o: memorizer.c
      $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) memorizer.c -o memorizer.o
```

Comment: I tried to fix the makefile but it still doesn't work. The thing I don't understand is because if I execute the command: "make abc" it returns me what I wrote above, while if I write "make -f Makefile.mak"
it seems to compile in fact it also gives me some warnings then but it tells me:
/ usr / bin / ld: /tmp/ccBHd9Tg.o: in function `main ':
/home/pollo/exam.c:111: undefined reference to `pthread_create '
/ usr / bin / ld: /home/pollo/exam.c:122: undefined reference to `pthread_join '
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile.mak: 12: exam.o] Error 1

Comment: @MaonnaPenzola this error does not relate to the `make`, it was produced by the linker of your c compiler.